# UITextField with a dropdown menu for iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, drop-down-menu, uitextfield

Is there an easy way to create a drop down menu for a UITextField, so that the user can type a custom entry or select one from a list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For drop down menu you can implement UITableView. You can populate this UItableview with your list.

Just declare it in ViewDidLoad method of your ViewController and then you can show or hid accordingly later.

```
    TableView = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,x,x,x) ];
    TableView.delegate = self;
    TableView.dataSource = self;
```

Add this to main view when user clickes on UITextField.

```
[self.view addSubView:TableView];
```

If you want user to select from given list only better option is UIButton instead of UITextField.

EDIT: I didn't notice it is the same as above answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can show a down arrow button besides uitextfield. And add a tableview of width same as textfield and height whatever you want and place it exactly below the textfield and keep it hidden. On click to downarrow button make tableView.hidden = NO so that it will appear as dropdown and again in didSelectRowAtIndexPath function of tableview make it hidden and place the selected row value in textfield. That's it.

Answer (score 3):

What you said is correct and we can also use textfield delegate method to populate the result in the table view, instead of using the down arrow.  When the user enters some text in the in the text field, the text field delegate method (didChangeText Delegate Method) will be called, in that method you can update the table view.  No need to add a dropdown arrow button in the text field.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, sure! below is the easiest way to implement dropdown on UITextField

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource
{
    //YOU JUST HAVE TO MAKE TEXTFIELD IN STORY BOARD AND LINK HERE
    @IBOutlet weak var txt_gender: UITextField!
    
    let gender = ["male","female","other"]
    var pickerView = UIPickerView()
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        pickerView.delegate = self
        pickerView.dataSource = self
        txt_gender.inputView = pickerView
        
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int
    {
        return gender.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String?
    {
      return gender[row]
    }
    
    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int)
    {
        txt_gender.text = gender[row]
        txt_gender.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

NOTE: You just have to make only UITextField in storyBoard and make outlet of that text field in your controller class.

Answer (score 0):

Just do this:

Add this to main view when user clickes on `UITextField`.

```
[self.view addSubView:TableView];
```